# nodejs: Keep within a proxy server

Tags: node.js, proxy

I am following [this code sample](https://gist.github.com/blumonkey/2b4ab631127bd9e66ede) to create my own CORS-proxy server. It works fine but when I click a link, I go to an invalid link.

[image: The proxy server is running]

Say, I loaded `localhost:1377/?url=www.github.com` in my server, the page loads.

[image: Github page is successfully proxied. Notice the Open Source tab (top-left)]

But when I click any link (say open-source), I end up going to `http://localhost:1337/open-source` rather than `localhost:1337/?url=http://www.github.com/open-source`

[image: Where I end up after clicking the link. Notice the URL]

How can I handle the requests to stay within my proxy server and keep browsing?

Thanks

**Edit:** Pictures

Comment: Can you update the question with more information?

Comment: @Scarecrow Will these suffice?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Anchortag]
Because of anchor tag of Open Source link. You need to parse the DOM.